# Boolean attribute in python object

Tags: python

It requires isgood to be a string only. I want it to be boolean. 
Also `self.__isgood = goodornot` should throw an error, why not?

```
class Animal:
    Name = ""
    isgood = None

    def setisgood(self,goodornot):
        self.__isgood = goodornot

    def nameset(self,name):
        self.Name = name


dog = Animal()
dog.setisgood(False)
dog.nameset("jaang")
print("Your pet is:"+dog.isgood)
```

Comment: First of all, you can't have leading `__` in a variable name and then access it as you are.

Comment: @COLDSPEED why did it not throw an error?

Comment: Second, you could've just separated that argument with a comma: `print("Your pet is:", dog.isgood)` A quick read of a python tutorial/doc would've solved this.

Comment: Because you have `Animal.isgood` regardless.

Comment: Whhhhhhhy are you use double-leading-underscores? Do you *want* name-mangling? Because that's how you get name-mangling. It doesn't *look* like you want name-mangling. Also, why do you have two random class-level variables, that look like the should be instance variables?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am new, do not know about name mangling -- will google. It was a typo......forgot to remove it...

Comment: So you just randomly decided to use two-leading-underscores? Well, that does something special in Python. I would just avoid it completely if you are new. Also, you are defining two class-level variables (i.e. "static") variables in your class, probably *not* what you want, especially since you *shadow* `Animal.Name` in `nameset`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as for class level variable (which I learnt only now that it is static) it was a formatting error in stackoverflow.

Comment: @kosmos huh? How so? Can you format your code to reflect what you are actually doing? Indentation has semantic content in Python. It is literally impossible to understand without the proper spacing.

Comment: I am confused.---

Comment: Well, now that you've clarified your formatting, you are *definitely* creating class-level variables. So it *wasn't* a formatting error.

Answer (score 1):

So then convert it to a string.

```
print("Your pet is: {}".format(dog.isgood))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Your pet is:"+dog.isgood)
```

is attempting to concatenate a boolean and a string, which cannot be done. In order to do so, you either need to convert dog.isgood into a string

```
print("Your pet is:" + str(dog.isgood))
```

like TheoretiCAL suggested in the comments, or use format

```
print("Your pet is:{}".format(dog.isgood))
```

like Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answer, or

```
print("Your pet is:%s" % dog.isgood)
```

or,

```
print("Your pet is:", dog.isgood)
```

All of these examples will result in the following output:

```
Your pet is:False
```

Edit:
Thank you juanpa for pointing this out. The spacing on the class is incorrect and should be causing an issue (I guess I assumed initially that it was just a copy paste thing).

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = ""
        self.isgood = None

    def setisgood(self,goodornot):
        self.isgood = goodornot

    def nameset(self,name):
        self.Name = name


dog = Animal()
dog.setisgood(False)
dog.nameset("jaang")
print("Your pet is:", dog.isgood)
```

Comment: This will print `"Your pet is:None"`, given the most reasonable interpretation of what the indentation looks like.

Comment: You are right, I will add a note about proper spacing.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using class-level (i.e. static) variables, then shadowing them with instance variables. Instead, you should just be using instance variables.

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be done. I was attempting to focus on answering the question as opposed to picking apart each aspect of the sample code. While I suspect that class-level variables were not intended based on your exchange with kosmos, it is entirely possible that it was intentional.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The original code gives the output "Your pet is:False" it would have given None if I write print("Your pet is:", Animal.isgood).

Comment: @kosmos no, it doesn't, not if you use `self.__isgood = goodornot` as you do in the code you posted, which I assume is what you mean by "original code". I'm running it right now.

Comment: Ok. Now everything is clear to me. Python is a quite different from Java.